# Javascript Loop skips array values

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to do a for loop with javascript to loop through an array and print the values for each of the array.
It is looking for distance and duration using Google distance matrix api.

My code is here: https://codepen.io/claireben/pen/oaVoNG

```js
var placesdest = ["11205", "11230", "11204", "11234", "33140", "90086"];
$(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {

    function calculateDistance(origin, destination) {
      var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
      service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
      }, callback);
    }

    function callback(response, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        $('.result').html(err);
      } else {
        var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
        var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
        if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
          $('.result').html("Better get on a plane. There are no roads between " +
            origin + " and " + destination);
        } else {
          var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
          var distance_value = distance.value;
          var distance_text = distance.text;
          var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration;
          var duration_value = duration.value;
          var duration_text = duration.text;
          var miles = distance_text.substring(0, distance_text.length - 3);
          if (duration_value < 3600) {
            $('.result').html("It is " + distance_text + " from " + origin + " to " + destination + " AND " + duration_text);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    /*$('#distance_form').submit(function(e){
        event.preventDefault();
        var origin = $('#origin').val();
        var destination = $('#destination').val();
        var distance_text = calculateDistance(origin, destination);
    });*/

    //var origin = document.getElementById("originq").innerHTML;
    var origin = "1762 Gerritsen Ave Brooklyn, New York 11229";
    // var destination = document.getElementById("destinationq").innerHTML;
    var destination = placesdest[i];
    var distance_text = calculateDistance(origin, destination);

    var para = "<div class='result'></div>";
    $("body").append(para);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<h2>Distance Between two Addresses</h2>
<!--<form id="distance_form">
    <label>Origin: </label>
    <input id="origin" type="text" name="origin"/>
    <br/>
    <label>Destination: </label>
    <input id="destination" type="text" name="destination"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate"/>
</form>-->
<div id="originq">1762 Gerritsen Ave Brooklyn, New York 11229
</div><div id="destinationq">1507 Coney Island Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11230
</div>

<div id="resultdura">
</div>
```

The problem is that it is not looping through the full array. It seems like it chooses one random one.

I am new to javascript. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: firstly the for loop, if dependent upon `placesdest` should be `<=5` or  `<6`

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar Ok, I did that change in codepen, but the issue remains. Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this can help you

declare functions before the for loop

```
var placesdest = ["11205", "11230", "11204", "11234", "33140", "90086"];
function calculateDistance(origin, destination) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
}

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    $('.result').html(err);
  } else {
    var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
    var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
    if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
      $('.result').html("Better get on a plane. There are no roads between " 
                    + origin + " and " + destination);
    } else {
      var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
      var distance_value = distance.value;
      var distance_text = distance.text;
      var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration;
      var duration_value = duration.value;
      var duration_text = duration.text;
      var miles = distance_text.substring(0, distance_text.length - 3);
      // you are validating the duration_value to be more 3600 to be able print
      if (duration_value < 3600) {
        $('#resultdura').append("It is " + distance_text + " from " + origin + " to " + destination + " AND " + duration_text + " <br>");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then create a function to call the for

```
function init () {
  for (var i=0; i < placesdest.length; i++) {
    //var origin = document.getElementById("originq").innerHTML;
    var origin = "1762 Gerritsen Ave Brooklyn, New York 11229";
     // var destination = document.getElementById("destinationq").innerHTML;
    var destination = placesdest[i];
    var distance_text = calculateDistance(origin, destination);
  }
}
```

finally call the init method to initialize the script

```
init()
```

- Remember that you are validating the duration time to print, it means that not all the destinations will be printed if they have duration time less than 3600

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're running into with your code is due to the asynchronous nature of your loop, and not handling it in some way.  There are many libraries, paradigms, etc to work with this problem, but it is something that you'll have to get a grip on in order to become a javascript professional.  I'll try to describe the issue so you can try to solve it within the context of your code rather than show you all these approaches.

First, I'll describe what's happening when you run that loop - it's going to fire off 6 requests, but when those requests come back with response data and which response goes with which request is up to you to handle.

When your request gets fired from the loop, you call your asynchronous block like this : `calculateDistance(origin,destination)` which will then fire the callback function when the request is done, how does your original loop pass into that calculateDistance function which calls the callback which request goes with which result?  It doesn't.

Looking at the existing code, the function 'init()' which runs the loop should at least pass the index variable `i` into the `calculateDistance(index,origin,distance)` function, which would then hypothetically give you the ability to pass that into the callback function, so it can match the result.  You could have an empty array with the same sizing called `results`, and in your callback function, if you pass the index variable in there `callback(response,status,index)` you could set the result with `results[index] = response`.  Then you'd have to keep track of when all the requests are done and then render them.

Anyhow, that's what's happening here, it's an async issue.  There's plenty of reading out there on it, and  it's one of the complex things about coding with javascript.  Javascript is single threaded, so understanding async paradigms is important, I won't describe it all here.